# $y=3^{\cos(x)}$ how to graph this trigonometric function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, graphing-functions

Please help me with graphing this function $y=3^{\cos(x)}$
without graphing software.

Thanks in advance for all your procedures.

Comment: Consider looking at $x=\frac{n\pi}{2}$ where n is a positive integer.

Comment: Well, how would you graph $\cos x$ without a grapher? What about $3^x$?

Comment: the graph of $y = 3^{\cos x}$ is going to bounce back and forth between the lines $y = \frac13$ and $y = 3$; but not periodic.

Answer (score 2):

Some observations:

- $u \mapsto 3^u$ is order-preserving, so $3^{\cos x}$ is increasing (resp. decreasing, stationary) precisely when $\cos x$ is increasing (resp. decreasing, stationary).
- $\cos x$ is periodic with period $2\pi$, hence so is $3^{\cos x}$.
- $\cos x$ takes values between $-1$ and $1$, so $3^{\cos x}$ takes values between $\frac{1}{3}$ and $3$.

With this information, and by plugging in some known values of $x$ (say, multiples of $\frac{\pi}{4}$ or $\frac{\pi}{6}$ or something), you should be able to make a reasonably accurate plot.